# Big number division leads to unexact result

Tags: python, math, solidity

I am test a solidity program, which deals with very large numbers (1e17).

The formula I'm testing is the following : int(1e17*(100-3)/(100-1))

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1e17*%28100-3%29%2F%28100-1%29) and the Solidity language tell me that it's equivalent to 97979797979797979.

The test fails however because Python returns 97979797979797984.

How can I get the right value with Python ?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point precision.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the `fractions` module works well here, since its division between two numbers is exact, in that it preserves the precision of the result.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> int(Fraction(10)**17*(100-3)/(100-1))
97979797979797979
>>>
```

(Here we avoid notation like `1e17` because it may resolve to an inexact `float` value.)

Comment: Just a note that `Fraction("1e17")` works, too, for a slightly more direct translation.